# `connect to private/policy-spf: No such file or directory` when receive mail by postfix in centos 7

Tags: postfix, email-server, centos7, spf

My system is centos 7 with postfix,dovecot,pypolicyd-spf, opendkim.
I can send mail but cannot receive mail,

I notice warnings as below:

```
Feb  6 20:01:09 srv-8327 postfix/smtpd[20391]: warning: connect to private/policy-spf: No such file or directory
Feb  6 20:01:09 srv-8327 postfix/smtpd[20391]: warning: problem talking to server private/policy-spf: No such file or directory
Feb  6 20:01:10 srv-8327 postfix/smtpd[20391]: warning: connect to private/policy-spf: No such file or directory
Feb  6 20:01:10 srv-8327 postfix/smtpd[20391]: warning: problem talking to server private/policy-spf: No such file or directory
```

I already set `debugLevel = 4` in `/etc/python-policyd-spf/policyd-spf.conf`.
How to find the problem of `python-policyd-spf`?

*Plus:*
**I finally solve this problem**:
In the `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, I change `unix:private/policy`  to `unix:private/policyd-spf`,bingo!

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf,reject_invalid_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_non_fqdn_recipient
```

Comment: In `postfix` you point to `private/policy-spf`. In your explanations you talk about `/etc/python-policyd-spf/policyd-spf.conf` Do you see the difference?

Comment: @RomeoNinov,I install spf by `yum install pypolicyd-spf`,tell me where is the problem?

Comment: You should edit `postfix` config to point to this file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally solve this problem:
In the `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, change `unix:private/policy` to `unix:private/policyd-spf`,bingo!

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu I solved this by changing

```
unix:private/policyd-spf
```

to

```
unix:private/policy-spf
```

in main.cf of postfix